# KAlgebra load problem

Tags: unity, kde, cpu-load, education

I want use KAlgebra on Unity. But loading of this program waste more time and after approximately 10 minute it be loaded but on any operation it freeze again. CPU load is so high when it is trying to load. I typed

```
kalgebra
```

in terminal and have take this errors rapidly:

```
X Error: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation) 1
Extension:    153 (Uknown extension)
Minor opcode: 19 (Unknown request)
Resource id:  0x540002c
X Error: BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation) 1
Extension:    153 (Uknown extension)
Minor opcode: 14 (Unknown request)
Resource id:  0x540002c
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I second that. I encounter the same bug on Kubuntu 13.10, KDE 4.11.3. The application is now essentially useless.